# PermissionError: [Errno13] Permission Denied

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, prompt, permission-denied

I tried to open the Jupyter notebook from Anaconda Powershell Prompt but below are the message that i have got. 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\defusedxml-0.6.0-py2.7.egg-info\PKG-INFO'

I tried to check the environment list with '''conda env list''' but i got the same error message.

i updated the anaconda and tried again, the error persist.

my python version is **3.7.3**.

I am not so sure what is wrong it.

Thanks in advance.